# Installing backuppc on Ubuntu 20.04 and ran some errors

Tags: command-line, 20.04, error-handling, backuppc

Ok, following the directions here : https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-backuppc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I get all the way down to the "Install backuppc on Ubuntu 20.04"

while in the directory backuppc...

Error I get below :

raigo@vikat:~/backuppc$ **./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate '30 Jun 2020' --version 4.4.0**
Distribution written to dist/BackupPC-4.4.0.tar.gz

raigo@vikat:~/backuppc$ **tar zxf BackupPC-4.4.0.tar.gz**

tar (child): BackupPC-4.4.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

raigo@vikat:~/backuppc$ **sudo tar zxf BackupPC-4.4.0.tar.gz**

tar (child): BackupPC-4.4.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried the `backuppc` package from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/backuppc)?

Comment: eeeem, i got it somehow. :)